# Is there any way to pass accessors nested json without knowing the nesting keys. Table throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-table

React Table : Is there any way to pass accessors nested json without knowing the nesting keys. React table throws error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {childnode}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
 columns = Object.keys(data).map(key=>{
            return {

                Header: key,
                accessor: key
            }
        });

   <ReactTable
                    id = "table"
                    data={data}
                    filterable
                    defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
                            const id = filter.pivotID || filter.id;
                            /*String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value*/
                             if (typeof filter.value === "object") {
                                return row[id] !== undefined
                                    ? filter.value.indexOf(row[id]) > -1
                                    : true;
                             }
                            /* else {
                                return row[id] !== undefined
                                ? String(row[id]).indexOf(filter.value) > -1
                                : true;
                            }*/
                             else {
                                 return row[id] !== undefined
                                     ? String(row[id].toLowerCase()).startsWith(filter.value.toLowerCase())
                                     : true;
                             }
                        }
                    }

                    columns =
                        {
                        columns
                    }

                    minRows = {0}
                    defaultPageSize={20}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
```

Comment: Could you share some code or setup a codesandbox - https://codesandbo x.io/s/new so that we can see whats happening.

Comment: @VijayMenon added code

Comment: Have you console logged columns and made sure that its an array of objects? Could you share a snippet of the JSON that you use to create columns

Comment: It is a nested JSON. and react table is not able to read the nested data.

Comment: ok. Just wanted to know if "columns" (the variable you use for react-table columns) has data when you console log and its an array of objects(which is the requirement as per react-table docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` variable that you use in order to create your columns **must be one json object, not a list of objects**. Since you don't include your `data` variable in your code above, I assumed it is a list, therefore the error. It is often the case that `data` refers to a list.

In order to get all the keys of an object, you might want to build your loop on the first object of data (assuming that all data objects have the same keys) :

```
const columns = Object.keys(data[0]).map(key=>{
    return {
        Header: key,
        accessor: key
    }
}))
```